# Is it possible to use lazy loading with many to many relation in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, lazy-loading

hi i have two entities User and Authority
they have many to many relation:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id") })
    private List<Authority> authorities = new ArrayList<Authority>(0);
```

when i use `FetchType.LAZY` and try to get the authorities in user i get the exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role
```

here's how i get the user object:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        User user = userDao.findUserByEmail(username);
        if (user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user with username '"
                    + username + "' found!");
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true,
                setUserAuthorities(user.getAuthorities()));
    }
```

i am using session factory to manage my transactions and `@Transactional` on the dao method.
 so is there's any ideas or solutions for this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is one of the most common exceptions. It means your session is closed at the time you try to read your collection.

The solution is to have an option session. Or to initialize the collection before having the session closed.

Btw, don't put `@Transactional` in the dao layer. Ideally it should be on the service layer.

Comment: is there is any samples for the two solutions you mentioned, and i updated my question so you can understand the case.

Comment: Google for OpenSessionInView. Or make the collection eager - it's a small one, so it won't be a problem

Comment: so OpenSessionInView will be the solution if the collection is big, right ? coz i have other many to many relation between authority and permission, and one authority will have lots of permissions so eager will be an overhead here, and it must be lazy.

Comment: and what do you think about this tutorial: http://cchweblog.wordpress.com/2009/10/10/using-opensessioninviewfilter-in-spring-web-application/

Comment: can you please suggest a good tutorial or links for using OpenSessionInView ?

Comment: also what do you think about this solution: `<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992335/spring-transactions-hibernate-lazy-initialization

Comment: looks fine. it uses an interceptor (native spring-mvc) rather than a filter